# Tensorflow: Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component

Tags: python, numpy, queue, tensorflow, label

I get the following error while running my input records function.

```
Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 1
Expected [2], got [4]
```

My labels are a (0,1) numpy array for each record. The set dimensions are 2. But it gives incorrect dimensions error.
Printing the tensor object after decoding also gives dimension 2

```
 Tensor("DecodeRaw_1:0", shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

The input function is:

```
def input():

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["path_to_record"])
print filename_queue

label = read_and_decode(f_queue)

min_queue_examples = n
labels_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [ label_record],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    num_threads=2,
    capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size,
    min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)

return labels_batch
```

Read record function is

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    features={

        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    })

)

label = tf.decode_raw(features['label'], tf.float32)
label.set_shape([2])
return label
```

Comment: The most likely cause of this error is that the `label.set_shape([2])` call is asserting a shape that doesn't match the true shape of the result of `tf.decode_raw()`. Try calling `sess.run(label)` to get the value of one of these tensors, and print its true shape.

Comment: maybe the dtype of tensor is wrong when read raw data from tfrecords